# Android: how can i change the initialized condition of switch statement?

Tags: android

i have a simple code and a really simple problem but i can't seem to have the answer....
am doing an experimental project ....i want the app to show different videos every time it's run.....first time running the app it will show the video 3 times second time you run the app it will show the video 4 times ...and so on ....so am using a switch statement as you can see here...`int num = 1;

```
        switch(num){
        case 1:
        for (int v = 0; v <3; v++) {
            //---report its progress---
            publishProgress(v);
            try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("Threading", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            }
                    num = num+1;
        break;
        case 2:
            for (int vv = 0; vv <4; vv++) {
                //---report its progress---
                publishProgress(vv);
                try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("Threading", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
                }
                   num = num-1;
        break;
        }`
```

the problem that am having that every time i run the app it will initialize the 'num' variable (which is the condition of the switch statement to one ...every time and so it will run the same case every time.....my question ....is this ....can i change the value of the num variable after it being initialized nad then give it another intilization when it run the app a second time?....and thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save num in a SharedPreferences on exit and retrieve it on load.

Answer (score 0):

Save your num variable to shared preference and at every run you can get and change value according to your requirement